# Lock window to workspace?

Tags: compiz

How do I lock a window to a specific workspace?

2 scenarios:

1. Launch application for first time, need it to be on specific workspace
2. Everytime I undock and dock my windows they lose their workspace and all go to the main work space

Would like to be able to say "evolution" goes to #5 always.

Comment: Please mention if it is not what you are looking for (and if so why :) )

Comment: That looks like a good duplicate. I didn't see it in my searches at all. Thanks!